# Transfer client side data to server side in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to build a site using Flask. I have very little knowledge about client side. I am trying to build a Jinja2 template which runs a script that gives me the user's latitude and longitude. The problem is that I have the latitude and longitude but I don't know how to transfer the data back to the server side from the script.

**This is my base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Tumu's App</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Hello. Lets share between close peoples.
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        alert(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
        }, function (error) {
        alert(error.code);
        }, {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0});
</script>"
<div>Share your location: <a href="/">Home</a></div>
<hr>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**My test.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Hi, {{ user.nickname }}!</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div><p>{{ post.author.nickname }} says: <b>{{ post.body }}</b></p></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**My views.py**

```
from app import app
from app import methods
from flask import render_template

# default route
@app.route('/')
def default():
    return render_template('base.html')

# generic test
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    user = {'nickname': 'rmad'}  # fake user
    return render_template('test.html', title='Flask Home',user=user)
```

How do I transfer the data from the script to the calling method in views.py?

Answer (score 3):

You need a new view that receives data from an AJAX call. Something like this should work:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/location', methods=['POST'])
def location():
    latitude = request.json.get('latitude')
    longitude = request.json.get('longitude')
```

Then on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/location',
    data: JSON.stringify({'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude}, null, '\t'),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
});
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it did not work out.
Please check if I have applied the changes properly
My base.html snippet
<script type="text/javascript">
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
  $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
    url: '/location',
    data: JSON.stringify({'latitude': position.coords.latitude, 'longitude': position.coords.longitude}, null, '\t'),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
  });
  }, function (error) {
  alert(error.code);
  }, {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0});
</script>"

And I added the /location route to views.py.

Comment: It didn't work? What didn't work? What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. I tried printing latitude and longitude. Didn't.
What i did in my views.py is that I added the /location route but I am still using default route to render the base.html. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using an html form is the solution for me. With "request.form.get", you can access client side data on server-side in Flask.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).